Поменять значения местами в javascript
На вход поступает два значения: a и b. Необходимо поменять значения переменных местами
const main = (a, b) => {
};
Я пытался указать main = (b, a), но не работает, нам вообще как-то не сильно объясняли как работать с этим языком, поэтому я даже не могу предположить каким путём выполнить условие

Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

@rusgeli Исправил и дополнил вопрос

Поставьте перед собой 2 коробочки(ваши переменные) в каждую положите монетку(значение переменных). Вам надо монетки в коробочке поменять местами. Как бы вы это сделали одной рукой, при условии, что вы можете одновременно работать только с одной монеткой? Думаю сразу становится очевидно, что вам нужна 3я коробочка(переменная), которая будет хранить промежуточное значение

@SwaD , Спасибо, я попытался сделать так как вы предложили, но, видимо, предполагается, что третья переменная использоваться не будет, либо я сделал что-то не так.
let c = a
a = b
b = c
return(a, b)

По описанию не понятно, какой ответ ожидается от функции. То что вы указали как раз меняет местами значения в переменных. Что должна вернуть функция?

функция должна поменять значения местами, допустим, на питоне сработал return(b,a), но на javascript почему-то такое не срабатывает

Вот несколько вариантов "обмена значениями"... https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.f0124aaa-6634a2e6-1687aa87-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript

На JS будет работать такой вариант return [b, a]... ;)

@ksa спасибо, очень помогли. Извините, если вопрос был немного затупный



let a = 2;
let b = 3;

[b,a] = [a,b];

console.log(a, b);

//------------------------

let main = (a,b) => {
  return [b,a];
}

let c = 5;
let d = 8;

[c, d] = main(c, d);
console.log(c, d);



